# Contact Without Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The contact form I'm using redirects after message has been sent but i would like the user to get a 'Message Sent' alert that would appear & disappears somewhere on the contact form instead. Meaning the page never refreshes nor does the user get taken away from the page or contact form.

Is this possible & if so could someone please show me the code i need to add to the current below...

```
<form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix"      action="http://www.demo.com/php/contactengine.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email"     onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
    <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value     == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
    <input class="contact_btn" name="submit"     type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "myemail";
$EmailTo = "myemail";
$Subject = "";
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) { 
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"   content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to this side of things.

Comment: You can submit the form via `AJAX`, google it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately the reason I'm an here is to gain expertise from someone who can talk me through it. To tell me to Google it defeats the purpose of this site but thanks anyway for pointing out the obvious

Comment: IMO it's good to go through some tutorials if you never heard about AJAX before. Just a code snippet is not enough to get the concept behind AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use AJAX to do this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#contact-form-face").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
      alert("Submitted!");
    });
  });
});
```

If the URL is on another domain, then CORS will be blocked. In order to avoid that, use:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

On the PHP file, that is being called.

---

For the form interaction:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#contact-form-face").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
      $("#post-ajax").html("Your Message Has Been Sent! Thank You For Contacting Us.").show();
      $("#contact-form-face").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="span9 contact_form">
  <div id="note"></div>
  <div id="fields">
    <div id="post-ajax" style="display: none;"></div>
    <form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix" action="http://www.demo.com/php/contactengine.php">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
      <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value     == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
      <input class="contact_btn" name="submit"     type="submit" value="Send Message" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- //CONTACT FORM -->
```

Comment: Ive add this script to my HTML page but now when i submit nothing happens - have i missed something?

Comment: That's right. Check your PHP's output. It would have sent the details. Did you get "Submitted" in the alert?

Comment: Ok now the message has came though to my email address with the correct information but no alert is presented on my page - do i to add something further to create the alert?

Comment: Check your console to see if there's any error preventing the alert from displaying?

Comment: Does this help..?

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.demo.com/php/contactengine.php. Origin http://www.demosite2.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (chctestv4, line 0)

Comment: Which helps? Sorry, did I miss anything?

Comment: Ah!!! CORS!!! Man, are you trying to use something crazy? `:P` Where are you calling the script from?

Comment: I moved my PHP script to another server because i had a feeling this server wasn't playing ball with it - is this the problem do you think?

Comment: That's the problem buddy! But you can enable CORS by seeing my updated answer.

Comment: Aaa ha! We now have an alert popup!!! My next question is how do i make this an alert that appears on my contact form instead of a popup? Thank you so much for your help & patience

Comment: Create a small text with `<div id="post-ajax" style="display: none;">` just before the form, and give it an ID. Then in the success function, try to unhide it by using `$("#post-ajax").show()`.

Comment: Man! You are making us do everything that we are not supposed to do! `;)`

Comment: Hahaha im so sorry but i really appreciate it. Ok I've tried this but it completely hides my form now :(

Comment: Show your code in a fiddle, if possible? Go to JSBin.com and do whatever you have did in your code. `:)` Or use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Ok just before i do that where do i add:

    $("#post-ajax").show()

I might have placed this in the wrong place

Comment: Most likely hahaha. So where does this code go? 

Do i add it to this...

$(function () {
  $("#contact-form-face").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
      alert("Submitted!");
    });
  });
});

Comment: You need to replace the `alert`. `;)`

Comment: Could i dare be a pain & ask you to show me this as an edit?

Comment: Bro, put the full code in pastebin or something, please!

Comment: Ok sorry for the hassle: https://jsfiddle.net/4nrj4un4/1/

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much, you have been fantastic. Works like a charm & much slicker looking than i had hoped ;-)

Comment: At the risk of pushing my luck...

How would i go about adding validation to this contact form & PHP with the unfilled out section turning red to indicate the error?

Comment: Yes of course sorry...

Ok if one of the fields has been left blank & the user clicks 'Send' i would like the field to highlight RED to indicate the mission information.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure.. It is possible. You have a lot of plugins to do that.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/